# How to Make a Basic SELECT FROM call to my MySQL database using RESTFUL API with SpringBoot-MyBatis-MySQL?

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, mybatis, ibatis

Question is pretty straightforward. I want to make a basic SELECT * FROm call to my MySQL database using the mentioned tools above.
I will be using XML-style mapper MyBatis config

So far Im successful when using string statements

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class ApplicationRestController {

    Actor actor;
    //this works easily because no connections to SQL are being made.
    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello() {
        return "HELO WORLD";        
    }
}
```

But what if I wanted to fetch data from my database? How to do this? Do I need SqlSession?

Does anyone have a useful link?

**THIS IS MY UPDATED ERROR:**

> Error creating bean with name 'applicationRestController': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'actorMapper'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'actorMapper' defined in file
>   [/Users/helios/Documents/workspace-sts-3.9.8.RELEASE/mybatis-sakila/target/classes/com/helios/mybatissakila/mappers/ActorMapper.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property
>   'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory]: Factory
>   method 'sqlSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to parse mapping
>   resource: 'class path resource
>   [mybatis-sakila/src/main/resources/mybatis-mapper/ActorMapper.xml]';
>   nested exception is
>
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource
>   [mybatis-sakila/src/main/resources/mybatis-mapper/ActorMapper.xml]
>   cannot be opened because it does not exist

These are my relevant files:

*Actor.java*

```
public class Actor {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int actor_id;
    private String first_name;
    private String last_name;
    private Date last_update;

    public int getActor_id() {
        return actor_id;
    }
    public void setActor_id(int actor_id) {
        this.actor_id = actor_id;
    }
    public String getFirst_name() {
        return first_name;
    }
    public void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
        this.first_name = first_name;
    }
    public String getLast_name() {
        return last_name;
    }
    public void setLast_name(String last_name) {
        this.last_name = last_name;
    }
    public Date getLast_update() {
        return last_update;
    }
    public void setLast_update(Date last_update) {
        this.last_update = last_update;
    }
}
```

*ActorMapper.java*

```
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Mapper;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;  
import com.helios.mybatissakila.model.Actor;

@Mapper
public interface ActorMapper {

    List <Actor> selectAllActors();
}
```

*ApplicationRestController.java*

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class ApplicationRestController {

    @Autowired
    ActorMapper actorMapper;

    //working as not connected to mysql
    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello() {
        return "MyBatis + SpringBoot + MySQL!";

    }
    //error 
    @GetMapping("/actors")
    public List<Actor> selectAllActors(){
            return actorMapper.selectAllActors();
    }
}
```

*ActorMapper.xml*

```
<resultMap id="ActorResultMap" type="Actor">
    <id column="actor_id" property="actor_id" jdbcType="INTEGER"/>
    <result column="first_name" property="first_name" />
    <result column="last_name" property="last_name" />
    <result column="last_update" property="last_update" />
</resultMap>

<select id="selectAllActors" resultMap="ActorResultMap">
        select * from actor
</select>
```

*application.properties*

```
server.port = 9090

spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakila
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = password
spring.datasource.dbcp2.test-while-idle= true
spring.datasource.dbcp2.validation-query= select 1

#mybatis entity scan packages
mybatis.type-aliases-package=com.helios.mybatissakila.model
#Mapper.xml location
mybatis.mapper-locations=classpath*:mybatis-sakila/src/main/resources/ActorMapper.xml
mybatis.typeAliasesPackage=com.helios.mybatissakila.model.Actor

logging.level.root=WARN
logging.level.sample.mybatis.mapper=TRACE
```

I have an inkling this is wrong, can you help me fix it as well? Is "**classpath**" just a boilerplate code which should be replaced with a real value?

```
mybatis.mapper-locations=classpath*:mybatis-sakila/src/main/resources/ActorMapper.xml
```

**Note**: I've managed to perform REST API calls using @Annotation style, but I want to use XML-style.

Comment: how may I help you?

Comment: @ilovesyntax help me sir, im stuck. i want to make a rest api using xml-style in mybatis-springboot-mysql using XML-style

Comment: That is so easy to do, Google it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is how I fixed it:

As I was indeed suspecting, the **classpath**  was a major factor to make this work. Once I've provided the correct path in *application.properties*:

```
mybatis.mapper-locations=classpath:/mybatis-mapper/ActorMapper.xml
```

I was able to make the SELECT call from MySQL. Isn't this interesting? :)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need SqlSession, MyBatis uses its own implementation, the only thing you need to do is to create MyBatis configuration and set all its dependencies.

Simply put, you need to do following:

Create your POJO:

```
public class Dog{
   private Long id;
   private String name;

  //Getters and Setters
}
```

Then you need to create MyBatis mapper interface in java:

```
public interface DogMapper{
   public void insert(Dog dog);
}
```

Then you have DogMapper.xml, where you put your queries.

And finally you would call your query as:

```
@Service
public class DogService{
   @Autowired
   private DogMapper dogMapper;

   public void insert(Dog dog){
       dogMapper.insert(dog);
   }
}
```

It is oversimplified way of how things work in MyBatis, however I would advise you to take a look at some MyBatis CRUD example. There will be detailed description how to make things done and furthermore very important configuration.

Comment: i know a bit about this. i've done annotations but what im trying to do is XML style as it supports more complicated SQL queries. thanks for your time.

Comment: After I see the changes you have done to your previous question, it looks like there is something wrong with xml file. Try to copy it as whole and not just some part of it, because there might be incorrectly set some settings.

Comment: Furthermore add how your database table looks like.

Comment: I've now fixed the xml file error i think as the error now is looking related to a missing 'bean' dependency